# How to save two related entries in a single form

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I am new to Django and I am creating a simple 2 page messageboard app (submit page and messageboard page)

I am struggling with the form for my submit page. As I am learning my way around Django I decided not to use the standard user model and opted to rather create a model (Poster) which has a one to one relationship with the message model.

Basically in one form I would like to add a message and a poster(foreign key) which has multiple fields.

Is it possible to achieve what I am trying to do?

Thanks in advance for the help.

I don't really know what to try or what to look for. I have included some code below.

```
Models
class Poster(models.Model):
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length = 15)
    email = models.EmailField()

class Message(models.Model):
    message_text = models.CharField(max_length=10000)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(Poster, on_delete=models.CASCADE) 



class MessageForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Message
        fields = ['full_name', 'phone_number', 'email', 'message_text']
```

Comment: I guess you can use the inline_formset factory in django, check the docs here (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/modelforms/#inline-formsets)

Comment: @SammyJ thanks. I will have a look.

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake is trying to use a `ModelForm` subclass which is for creating or updating one object (database row) only.

Use a plain `forms.Form` with the fields you want. You'll have to explicitly code them as `CharField`, `EMailField`, etc. Then in `form_valid` (assuming your view is a `FormView`) you will do something like

```
poster = Poster()
poster.full_name = form.cleaned_data['full_name']
# ditto for phone_number and email
poster.save()
message = Message( user=poster, 
    message_text = form.cleaned_data['message_text'] )
message.save()
```